# Use Cases of NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a question about Nifi and its capabilities as well as the appropriate use case for it.

I've read that Nifi is really aiming to create a space which allows for flow-based processing. After playing around with Nifi a bit, what I've also come to realize is it's capability to model/shape the data in a way that is useful for me. Is it fair to say that Nifi can also be used for data modeling?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data modeling might well mean many things to many folks so I'll be careful to use that term here.  What I do think in what you're asking is very clear is that Apache NiFi is a great system to use to help mold the data into the right format and schema and content you need for your follow-on analytics and processing.  NiFi has an extensible model so you can add processors that can do this or you can use the existing processors in many cases and you can even use the ExecuteScript processors as well so you can write scripts on the fly to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 9):

Data modeling is a bit of an overloaded term, but in the context of your desire to model/shape the data in a way that is useful for you, it sounds like it could be a viable approach.  The rest of this is under that assumption.

While NiFi employs dataflow through principles and design closely related to flow based programming (FBP) as a means, the function is a matter of getting data from point A to B (and possibly back again).  Of course, systems aren't inherently talking in the same protocols, formats, or schemas, so there needs to be something to shape the data into what the consumer is anticipating from what the producer is supplying.  This gets into common enterprise integration patterns (EIP) [1]  such as mediation and routing.  In a broader sense though, it is simply getting the data to those that need it (systems, users, etc) when and how they need it.

Joe Witt, one of the creators of NiFi, gave a great talk that may be in line with this idea of data shaping in the context of Data Science at a Meetup.  The slides of which are available [2].

If you have any additional questions, I would point you to check out the community mailing lists [3] and ask any additional questions so you can dig in more and get a broader perspective.

- [1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_Integration_Patterns
- [2] http://files.meetup.com/6195792/ApacheNiFi-MD_DataScience_MeetupApr2016.pdf
- [3] http://nifi.apache.org/mailing_lists.html